# How do you switch applications in mac osx when in starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

I would sometimes like to follow team liquids wiki in some maps as a walkthrough(like the secret mission) but it seems I can't "alt-tab" in SC2. How do you do this is mac osx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command + M will set you in windowed mode.  From there any number of methods will let you switch applications...expose, spaces, alt-tab etc.

If you aren't in windowed mode you can't alt-tab or switch between apps.

Comment: In Mac OS X, its <kbd>Command+Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In the Options under Graphics, set the Display Mode to 'Windowed (Fullscreen)'.  At that point, SC2 will take up the entire screen (unlike command+M) but you will still be able to switch between applications with command-Tab just like with any other application.